# Pyspark - Creat schema from nested list of dict

Tags: python, pyspark, schema

Question:

I have a list of tuples of dictionaries that I need to convert into a dataframe using schema in Pyspark. The list is in the following format:

```py
tvo=[('a',
  {'key1': 'val1',
   'key2': val2,
   'key3': val3,
   'key4': val4,
   'key5': {'key_a': 'val_a',
            'key_b': 'val_b',
            'key_c': 'val_c',
            'key_d': 'val_d',
            'key_e': 'val_e',
            'key_f': 'val_f',
            'key_g': 'val_g',
            'key_h': 'val_h',
            'key_i': 'val_i',
            'key_j': 'val_j',
            'key_k': 'val_k'}}),
 ('b',
  {'key1': 'val1',
   'key2': val2,
   'key3': val3,
   'key4': val4,
   'key5': {'key_a': 'val_a',
            'key_b': 'val_b',
...       
            'key_h': 'val_h',
            'key_i': 'val_i',
            'key_j': 'val_j',
            'key_k': 'val_k'}}),
...   
]
```

Here is the current code for the target schema:

```py
target_schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('recomment', StructType([
        StructField('signals', MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True)),
        StructField('oscillators', MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True))
    ]), True)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(tvo, target_schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

However, the resulting dataframe simply shows null values:

```
+----------------+------------+
|pair            |recomment   |
+----------------+------------+
|a               |{null, null}|
|b               |{null, null}|
|c               |{null, null}|
|...             |{null, null}|
|z               |{null, null}|
+----------------+------------+
```

I need to fix the code to generate a dataframe with the correct values.